# Time difference between 21:00 and 06:00 from another time

Tags: php, time, difference

I have a website that should calculcate "extra money" for workers when they work between 21:00 and 06:00.
How can I calculate the hours between 21:00 and 06:00? The input may be outside the range 21 and 06, eg start 19:30 and stop 07:15...

Comment: you could save date with time then calculate the time difference

Comment: I don't have trouble by calculate the difference between start_time and stop_time... The issue is to calculate the difference between 21:00 and 06:00, inside start_time and stop_time.
Start_time=20:00, stop_time=07:00, output should be 09:00
Start_time=22:00, stop_time=06:00, output should be 08:00

Comment: So calculate the difference between max(start_time,21) and min(stop_time,6).

Comment: You need full dates. Then you can easily calculate time difference using the DateTime methods.

Comment: Maybe I have explained myself bad...suggestions only let me calculate the difference between two times, and that I can manage. The solution I'm looking for, or suggestion for solution, is...
Start_time=20:00, End_time=07:00. Output is the difference between 21:00 and 06:00, 09:00 hours.
If start_time=22:00, end_time=05:00, output is 07:00 hours.
If start_time=03:00, end_time=10:00, output is 03:00 hours.
The output should only be the difference in time between 21:00 and 06:00, no mather what the input is...